# OSX Facebook Notifications saying "New Message" instead of the actual message

Tags: macos, notifications, facebook

Up until today, when I would get a message notification from Facebook, it would say the content of the message and the sender. I had to delete and re-add Facebook to my "Internet Accounts" preference pane because I changed my password. Now it just says that I have a "New Message" whenever I get a message. How do I change it back? Re-adding my Facebook account and restarting don't fix it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate, patrix. I went looking for other people asking before I posted, but I was using the wrong keywords.